# Replacing a fragment within a tab. Previous fragment is still active behind the new one

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, android-tabs

I'm currently have 3 tabs. Each tab on selection be it through swiping or pressing the tab will load a fragment which then inflates a XML layout. I am also using a viewpager along with a fragmentPagerAdapter.

In one of the tabs ( and the rest in the future) I want to be able to click on a button in the fragment and for the current fragment in the current tab to be replaced with a new tab. At the moment I'm half way there, the button will show the new tab but it's on top of the old one, and I can still see the old button that called the new fragment and interact with it, as well as the button on the new tab.

How do I ensure that the fragment is replaced properly? And also that the old fragment is placed on the backstack so I can go back to it with the tab?

Here is my code for changing the fragment

```
public class CreateWorkoutFragment extends Fragment {

    private Button addExerciseButton;
    private FragmentNavigationHelper fragmentNavigationHelper;
    static CreateWorkoutFragment instance;

    public CreateWorkoutFragment() {
    }

    /*public static CreateWorkoutFragment newInstance()
    {
          if(instance == null)
          {
              instance = new CreateWorkoutFragment();
          }

        return instance;
    } */


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        ViewGroup view = (ViewGroup) inflater.inflate(R.layout.create_workout, null);

        fragmentNavigationHelper = new FragmentNavigationHelper();
        addExerciseButton = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.addExercise_button);
        addExerciseButton.setOnClickListener( new OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //fragmentNavigationHelper.changeFragmentWithTab((Fragment) new ExerciseCategoryFragment());

                Fragment newFragment = new ExerciseCategoryFragment();
                FragmentTransaction transaction = getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, newFragment);
                transaction.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN);
                transaction.addToBackStack(null);
                transaction.commit();
            }
        });

        return view;
    }
}
```

I think the problem might be because I'm using the id of the relativelayout that everything is wrapped in within my createWorkout.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/createWorkout_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/createWorkoutTitle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:contentDescription="@string/begin_workout_title_description"
        android:src="@drawable/create_workout_image"
        android:visibility="visible" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/day_textview"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/createWorkoutTitle"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="19dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="14dp"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/dateMonth_textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/day_textview"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/addExercise_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/NFCToggle_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/addExercise_button"  />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Any help or push in the right direction would be greatly appreciated, as I really am stumped at the minute and can't seem to find anything that's leading me close to the answer.

Thanks in advance